# Unable to deduce why one imagePuller pod of JuPyterhub fails while the rest three are successfully created

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, kubernetes-helm, jupyterhub

I am deploying jupyterhub on a kubernetes cluster. In the config.yaml file, I am specifying a registry and the image tag. 
While 3 pods are successfully created, one is not.

I could not find much content pertaining to jupyter-hub.

The helm chart can be found here(https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart/jupyterhub-0.8.2.tgz).

My config for values.yaml is:

```
proxy:
  secretToken: "some token"
singleuser:
  image:
    name: acc_id.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/demo
    tag: 12c
  lifecycleHooks:
    postStart:
      exec:
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", 'ipython profile create; cd ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup; echo ''run_id = "sample" ''> aviral.py']
  imagePullSecret:
    enabled: true
    registry: acc_id.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
    username: aws
    email: aviral@abcd.com
    password: <my pw>
```

When I describe the pods:

```
➜  jupyterhub kubectl get pods -n jhub
NAME                       READY   STATUS                  RESTARTS   AGE
hook-image-awaiter-2xxfx   1/1     Running                 0          13m
hook-image-puller-4f9mk    1/1     Running                 0          13m
hook-image-puller-jshlk    1/1     Running                 0          13m
hook-image-puller-wj8r6    1/1     Running                 0          13m
hook-image-puller-wlgnh    0/1     Init:ImagePullBackOff   0          13m
hub-6766fc7586-zdf9n       1/1     Running                 0          35m
proxy-65f559ff89-md7r5     1/1     Running                 0          20h
```

As you can see, the pod named `hook-image-puller-wlgnh` is in Init:ImagePullBackOff mode.

While describing it, under the `events` section, I get:

```
Failed to pull image "acc_id.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/demo:12c": [rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized: authentication required, rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled]
```

However, the other 3 pods are running and they were able to pull the same image.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a know issue, as reported on GitHub [Occasional ImagePullBackOff Errors when pulling large docker images #59376](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/59376), this bug was not resolved and there seems to be several workarounds.

- One is to recreate the `pod` that failed,
- Another one is to increasing the `image-pull-progress-deadline`
- Or removing the namespace in which it was deployed and deploying it again.

Also you can try what @[P Ekambaram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3270785/p-ekambaram) mentioned which would be running `docker pull <IMAGE>`.

Comment: I tried the first method by deleting the pod, it started in the init state all again and haven't started running for so long. So, the first method is not working. As for the second method, how can I do it?

Comment: What have you changed to get this error? Also have you tried setting `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent`? Have you tried removing the deployment and redeploying it?